# Re-quantize an RGB image uniformly in the ratio R:G:B = 3:3:2 in Scilab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, scilab

Can we Re-quantize an RGB image uniformly in the ratio R:G:B = 3:3:2 using Scilab ?. and compare it with YCbCr 4:2:0 format and quantize the components uniformly in the ratio Y:Cb:Cr = 4:2:2, 
and then convert back to RGB? using SCilab

And How to do so? are there any additional tools required?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [SIVP](http://sivp.sourceforge.net/). This is an image and video toolbox for Scilab. Install it through the Atoms package manager.

With [SIVP](http://sivp.sourceforge.net/) you have access to the following functions:

- [rgb2ycbcr](http://sivp.sourceforge.net/func-list-0.5.0/rgb2ycbcr.htm)
- [ycbcr2rgb](http://sivp.sourceforge.net/func-list-0.5.0/ycbcr2rgb.htm)
- [imabsdiff](http://sivp.sourceforge.net/func-list-0.5.0/imabsdiff.htm)

I think that will help you on your way.

More functions are listed [here](http://sivp.sourceforge.net/func-list-0.5.0/whatis.htm)